# Rust code cannot link with a C library compiled on Windows because there is an unresolved external symbol

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-errors, linker, rust, ffi

I've been trying to get Rust to link with a C library on Windows, but Rust is unable to find the functions I need. It seems like my function signature is wrong, but Rust can find the `.lib` file.

I narrowed it down to very simple C and Rust code, but still can't figure out how to get it to work:

**test.c** -- compiled with Visual Studio 2015

```c
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct MyStruct {
    int32_t i;
} MyStruct;

MyStruct my_func(const MyStruct *s) {
    MyStruct result;
    result.i = s->i + 1;
    return result;
}

int32_t my_func2() {
    return 42;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

**lib.rs**

```
extern crate libc;

use libc::int32_t;

#[link(name = "MyLib")]
extern {
    pub fn my_func2() -> int32_t;
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        unsafe {
            assert_eq!(42, my_func2());
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively **lib.rs**:

```
extern crate libc;

use libc::int32_t;

#[repr(C)]
pub struct MyStruct {
    i: int32_t
}

#[link(name = "MyLib")]
extern {
    pub fn my_func(s: *mut MyStruct) -> MyStruct;
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        unsafe {
            let mut s = MyStruct{ i: 10 };
            let s = my_func(&mut s as *mut MyStruct);
            assert_eq!(11, s.i);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error message I get:

```
   Compiling test v0.1.0
error: linking with `link.exe` failed: exit code: 1120
  |
// snip (but the MyLib.lib is in here)
  = note: test-01aaa83d15a1dde3.0.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol my_func referenced in function _ZN8test5tests8it_works17h52c29448f9d86a1aE
C:\<--omitted-->-01aaa83d15a1dde3.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

error: aborting due to previous error

error: Could not compile `test`.
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "test"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["<-- omitted -->"]

[dependencies]
libc = "0.2.17"
```

Comment: Please mention the OS (you appear to be using Windows), your Cargo.toml and however you compile `MyLib`. I seem to remember from my VC++ days that VC++ would require a `__declspec(dllexport)` to be placed in front of exported symbols...

Comment: Can you try the `__declspec(dllexport)`?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Even for compiling a `.lib`, not a `.dll`?. And same problem

Comment: Probably not; do you have a tool to check the symbols contained in your `.lib`? There might be name mangling/decoration at play too.

Comment: Turns out that nothing was exported in the .lib...

Comment: Great! If you can write an answer on how to check whether a symbol is exported and how to export it, it'll make a good contribution for people attempting FFI on Windows :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you check to see that your `.lib` file has any symbols / exported functions?:

```
> dumpbin /exports /symbols MyLib.lib
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.00.24215.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file MyLib.lib

File Type: LIBRARY
```

This means that your `.lib` file does not have any exported symbols. You might have thought to use `__declspec(dllexport)`, but that does not seem to work for static `.lib` files.

Visual Studio is a bit of a pain to work with, but here's how you get it working in VS 2015:

1. Create a new "Module-Definition File" (.def)
2. Fill in the details:

   ```
   LIBRARY MyLib
   EXPORTS
       my_func  @1
       my_func2 @2
   ```
3. Right click on your project, click on properties, and make sure your project's configurations are correct:

   [image: Configuration Type: Static library (.lib)]
4. Under Librarian, make sure you set the `.def` file:

   [image: Module Definition File Name: test.def]
5. Build the `.lib` file. If you did this correctly, running `dumpbin` again should look something like this:

   ```
   > dumpbin /exports /symbols MyLib.lib
   Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.00.24215.1
   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


   Dump of file MyLib.lib

   File Type: LIBRARY

   COFF SYMBOL TABLE
   000 01015E97 ABS    notype       Static       | @comp.id
   001 00000000 SECT2  notype       External     | __IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR_MyLib
   002 C0000040 SECT2  notype       Section      | .idata$2
   003 00000000 SECT3  notype       Static       | .idata$6
   004 C0000040 UNDEF  notype       Section      | .idata$4
   005 C0000040 UNDEF  notype       Section      | .idata$5
   006 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR
   007 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | MyLib_NULL_THUNK_DATA

   String Table Size = 0x5C bytes

   COFF SYMBOL TABLE
   000 01015E97 ABS    notype       Static       | @comp.id
   001 00000000 SECT2  notype       External     | __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR

   String Table Size = 0x1D bytes

   COFF SYMBOL TABLE
   000 01015E97 ABS    notype       Static       | @comp.id
   001 00000000 SECT2  notype       External     | MyLib_NULL_THUNK_DATA

   String Table Size = 0x22 bytes

        Exports

          ordinal    name

                1    my_func
                2    my_func2

     Summary

             D2 .debug$S
             14 .idata$2
             14 .idata$3
              8 .idata$4
              8 .idata$5
             12 .idata$6
   ```
6. Copy the generated `.lib` file (ensuring you do so from the correct directory; note that 64 bit and 32 bit compile to different folders) to your Rust project's root directory:

   ```
   + MyRustProject/
    \
     + src/
     + Cargo.toml
     + MyLib.lib
   ```
7. Go back to the build configurations and build a `.dll`:

   [image: Configuration Type: Dynamic Library (.dll)]
8. Copy that `.dll` in the same place as the `.lib`

Now when you build your Rust project, it should work. Note that you must build your VS project for the same platform as the Rust one, so, in my case, that meant x64, rather than x86.

For more information on `.def` files, see [Microsoft's official documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/module-definition-dot-def-files)

Comment: Well, that was painful... I hope someone comes along with a way of streamlining this oO

Comment: @MatthieuM. If it counts, I wrote a quick python script to generate the `.def` file as long as I put an `MY_LIB_API` macro before each function I want. So just gonna say that that's possible and nice